# Parse OpenXML Office Docs in Node.js project

Tags: node.js, openxml

We want to control office docs properties like Readonly,Print, save etc using openxml in our node.js project, we  already sorted out mechanisms for reading and writing openxml with JSZip, and we need help to restructure and parse the openxml context to a present document then we can make this work.can you guys please suggest any recommendations, thanks in advance